# Adjusting width of flash content without changing aspect ratio

Tags: html, flash

I want to maintain width of `600 px` and height be adjusted accordingly in order to *maintain aspect ratio*. How can that be achieved?

I m using following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.registerObject("myFlashContent", "9.0.0");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="600" id="myFlashContent">
            <param name="movie" value="swffile.swf" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="swffile.swf" width="600">
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post the content of `swfobject.js`

Comment: edit:<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>...instead of swfobject.js